# Vim doesn't use the correct indentation in Python files

Tags: indentation, whitespace, tab-characters, filetype-python

I have encountered something that I have never seen before in Vim.  While I was tentatively modifying some of the source code for software I've been planning to work on, I noticed vim was displaying incorrect spacing for the line of code that I added.  Gedit shows the code with the correct spacing.  I know Gedit has the correct spacing because the Python code delivers errors if I change the code in Vim to be where it appears to belong within the Vim window.  I have attached the Images below.  The line that I added is the line that says: print "I am about to evaluate a factorial".  I have included my short .vimrc file as well.  Has anyone seen this?  I have been using vim for months now and can't recall anything like this ever occuring.

- Vim (Incorrect):

  [image: Vim wrong]
- Gedit (Correct):

  [image: Gedit right]
- Vimrc:

  [image: Vimrc file]

Comment: I know this might be a bit of a hassle, but could you turn on `set list listchars=tab:>-` and re-upload the first (Vim) picture? I think it would help us see what's going on with the tabs.

Comment: It looks to me like your vimrc is working just fine. The tab is 4 spaces as desired. However, the *rest* of the document is using only spaces. I would just use spaces on this line to fix the issue. Or at any rate, stay consistent between using tabs and spaces for indentation.

Comment: Using all spaces worked, thank you.  I am surprised however as I would expect the tab to not be interpreted differently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It gets reset by the Python filetype plugin; from `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
" As suggested by PEP8.
setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8
```

This file is loaded every time a Python file is loaded.

To override it add this in your vimrc:

```
augroup python
    autocmd!
    " Add shiftwidth and/or softtabstop if you want to override those too.
    autocmd FileType python setlocal noexpandtab tabstop=4
augroup end
```

This will get loaded after the ftplugin file, overriding the settings from there.

I would recommend against using tabs in Python files, as the community standard is to use spaces.

Comment: Yeah so make sure you have `filetype plugin on` in your vimrc. I wouldn't override the `set tabstop=8` though. The reason is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation)

Answer (score 3):

Solution for me was to add this line after the filetype plugin on into my `~/.vimrc` file

```
filetype plugin on
autocmd FileType python setlocal noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the file `python.vim`, path in Debian 9 /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/python.vim, contains the following code

```
if !exists("g:python_recommended_style") || g:python_recommended_style != 0
    " As suggested by PEP8.
    setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8
endif
```

the best to turn it off is to put

```
let g:python_recommended_style=0
```

into `.vimrc` and the code would not execute at all, because the plugin is usually executed after `.vimrc`.

Another solution is to create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` hook as suggested in https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13538/41302

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to link to this answer in the comment to https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/why-is-set-noexpandtab-in-my-vimrc-ignored-when-i-open-a-file/13538