# Why is "set noexpandtab" in my ~/.vimrc ignored when I open a file?

Tags: indentation, filetype, filetype-python

I'm using Mac OS X 10.12 and I have `set noexpandtab` in my `~/.vimrc`

There are 2 different behaviors :

1. `$ vim file.py`

   If run Vim (8.0) to open one file and type `:set expandtab?`, it says `expandtab`
2. `$ vim`

   If I run Vim by itself and type `:set expandtab?`, it says `noexpandtab`

Why is `set noexpandtab` in my `~/.vimrc` ignored when I open a file ?

`:verbose set expandtab?` says:

```
expandtab
      Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0627/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim
```

Comment: You probably have a setting set only for python files. Use `:verbose set expandtab?` to find out where the setting was last set from.

Comment: you probably have a python plugin. Plugins can and will overwrite your vimrc. With Marth's comment you'll find out that this is the case. You can overwrite the settings again, with a file in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Do I have to move my `set noexpandtab` in a file inside `.vim/after/ftplugin/` directory ?

Comment: yes, you could put it in a file called `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/py.vim` or use an autocmd. look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375119/override-options-set-by-ftplugins-in-vim

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo It seems that it works only with a file called `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`. Can you please update your comment and convert it to an answer ?

Comment: @SebMa ups sorry, of course it is python.vim ... can't edit my comment, but corrected it in my answer.

Comment: You can also comment the corresponding line in the plugin file (and add the settings you want).

Comment: Though possibly unrelated to this particular OP this question can arise when someone has either deliberately or inadvertently `set paste`. The `paste` settings also applies `noexpandtab`, but `expandtab`, if originally set, is restored once you `set nopaste`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not ignored, it is overwritten by your filetype plugin. In this case the python plugin. You can verify that like Marth said, with the `:verbose` command:

```
:verbose set expandtab?
```

If you want to overwrite the setting in the filetype plugin, you should go for one of the following ways:

1. Put your settings in a after file:
   `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`, see `:h after` for more information.
2. Use an autocommand: `:autocmd FileType python setlocal noexpandtab`, see `:h auto` for more information. *This must be done after the line which activates the filetype plugins (possibly something like `:filetype plugin on`)

Note the `setlocal`, you should use this instead of `set` in both, the autocmd and your after file. Else you can get it all mixed up if you open different filetypes in the same instance.

DISCLAIMER: Most Lines are directly taken from this SO post: [Override options set by ftplugins in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375119/override-options-set-by-ftplugins-in-vim) or the comment of Marth. This answer only adjust them for the given problem. So if this helped you, think about leaving an upvote there!