# Option set in vimrc is overwritten - nvim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, options

I'm trying to disable `autochdir` in `nvim` by adding the following in `init.vim`:

```
set autochdir!
```

but when I start `nvim`, I check the value of this option by `echo &autochdir` and find it equals to `1`.

I though it may be overwritten by `Python filetype` as mentioned these two posts ([Why is “set noexpandtab” in my ~/.vimrc ignored when I open a file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/why-is-set-noexpandtab-in-my-vimrc-ignored-when-i-open-a-file/13538#13538) and [Vim displaying incorrect indentation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/vim-displaying-incorrect-indentation)).So I tried adding the following to my `vimrc`:

```
augroup python
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python set autochdir!
augroup end
```

but it doesn't solve the problem.

Why is this option overwritten and how can I force it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something funny is going on here. If you want to disable the ['autochdir'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'autochdir'), use

```
:set noautochdir
```

If you use the the `!`, this means it basically toggles the option. So whenever you happen to resource your .vimrc (or init.vim) file it silently toggles the value, which might be unexpected.

However, if you read the help for that setting, it clearly indicates this option is off by default. So you can also just skip the whole command at all ;)

```
augroup python
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python set autochdir!
augroup end
```

Secondly your autocommand may work fine and disable the autochdir. Sadly, this might come to late so that Nvim already switched to the specified directory and only afterwards it turns off the setting.

You can always check the option value when it was set and by what script by using:

```
:verbose set autochdir?
```

In general I would always recommend to either leave this global option off, or on. But do not toggle it often within a session. It might be confusing, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the toggle point. Thanks for clarifying it. 
In nvim, I think this option is ON by default. At least this is how it behaved before.

Comment: Not according to the [current documentation](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/0b3555b5dda477f647653487d6345ce9cc45304c/runtime/doc/options.txt#L611-L620)

Comment: `'autochdir'` has never defaulted on ON for nvim.